# Fallback for FormData in IE 8/9

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fileapi

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) does not exist in IE 8/9 but I need that functionality in those browsers. Is there a nice fallback for this?

I would try to send over json data, but I need to pass over a file to the server. I append this file to the `formData` in modern browsers and just submit an `XHR` request. Because `FormData` does not exist in IE 8/9 this obviously fails.

```
// I cant seem to get this to work with a file.
$.ajax({
    url: '/genericHandlers/UploadDocsFile.ashx',
    type: "POST",
    data: model.toJSON(),
    contentType: 'application/json'
    }).done(function  (data) { 
       log('stuff happened!');
    });
```

Maybe an alternative is to create a fake form object in js then append the data to that?

Comment: Would love a polyfill for the window.FormData method.

Comment: Then i present to you a new FormData [polyfill](https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData/) Still depend on constructing blobs unfortunately... Maybe you can use this also: [Blob.js](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js). To read a file you would need flash

Answer (score 8):

I know only one possible solution, but it's not really 1-1 fallback for IEs. There are no possible communication API for sending files, because you cannot bind input fields in old browsers, like in a modern ones using FormData. But you can send whole form using an iframe. For this case you can use [jquery.form](https://github.com/malsup/form) plugin that support XHR DataForm and iframe (data sends with iframe when browser do not FormData API support).

Answer (score 4):

You can send the file manually using XMLHttpRequests, there is lots of information on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files).

You could test if the browser can use the `FormData` object first with:

```
if(typeof FormData !== 'undefined')
   ...
```

MDN has a [this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#Building_an_XMLHttpRequest_manually) which you could modify for the fallback:

```
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
var urlEncodedData = "";
var urlEncodedDataPairs = [];
var name;

// We turn the data object into an array of URL encoded key value pairs.
for(name in data) {
  urlEncodedDataPairs.push(encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[name]));
}

// We combine the pairs into a single string and replace all encoded spaces to 
// the plus character to match the behaviour of the web browser form submit.
urlEncodedData = urlEncodedDataPairs.join('&').replace(/%20/g, '+');
```

Comment: @Karson Really? As per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#History_and_support Microsoft added the XMLHttpRequest object identifier to its scripting languages in Internet Explorer 7.0 released in October 2006.

Comment: The concept can be applied to IE 5&6 with ActiveXObjects if you really wanted as well

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not strictly address the question you asked, and for that reason I understand if Mods will remove it.

However, your question was closely related to an issue I was researching which is **how to offer drag and drop uploads via FormData() with graceful degradation for older browsers**?

There is a wonderful library called [dropzone.js](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#donate) which offers a perfect solution to my problem. Perhaps the best part is that the library offers out-of-the-box graceful degradation to support file uploads on older browsers, [as detailed here](http://yaizabailen.com/upload-files-from-a-web-browser-support-for-old-and-modern-browsers-dropzone-js-and-the-jquery-iframe-transport-js-plugin/#prettyPhoto).

To paraphrase the source:

> Fortunately if the browser is not supported, the dropzone.js library shows a customizable fallback class that contains an input field and a submit button.

I hope this information helps someone who is, like me, searching for a simple to implement and elegant solution for file uploads.