# how to make new FormData() work on IE browsers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I make this work on IE?
This won't work on IE, new FormData() api is not supported by IE browsers, is there any other api equivalent to new FormData() in IE?

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append( "userfile", $("#userfile")[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
    url : '/user/ajax_upload/',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType:false,
    cache: false,
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend :function(){
    },
    success : function( data ) {
        $('#popupbox').html(data);  
    }
});
```

Comment: this will help:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852446/fallback-for-formdata-in-ie-8-9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its better to use jquery form Js for submitting images over ajax. I found it better than `FormData()`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.form.js"></script>

function update_professional_details(){
    var options = { 
                url     : '/validateform/personal',
                type    : $("#personal_edit_form").attr('method'),
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function( data ) {
                    var msg = data.msg;
                    if(data.status == 'success'){
                        $("#msg_data").html("Updated successfully, redirecting...")
                        $("#personal_edit_form").submit();
                    }else{
                        $('p[class$="_error2"]').html('');
                        var msg = data.msg;
                        $.each(msg, function(k, v) {
                            $('.'+k+'_error2').html(v);
                        });
                    }
                },
            }; 
            $('#personal_edit_form').ajaxSubmit(options);
                return false;
        }

    $('#updatepersonal').click(function(){
        update_professional_details();
            return false;
    });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on _found it better_?

Comment: The smart money says its just an euphemism for "this way worked, the other way didn't, i dont know why", as it so often is...

Answer (score 4):

Actually i made an alteration to my code to be able to use $.ajax in all other browsers and just made an iframe for the IE browsers like this.

mailer.php

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <iframe src="form.php"></iframe>
<![endif]-->

<![if !IE]>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        //Program a custom submit function for the form
        $("#form").submit(function(event){

          //disable the default form submission
          event.preventDefault();

          //grab all form data  
          var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

          $.ajax({
            url: $("#form").attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (returndata) {
              alert(returndata);
            }
          });

          return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<?php include_once ('form.php'); ?>

<div id="email-success"></div>
<![endif]>
```

form.php

```
<form id="form" action="form-exec.php" target="_self" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="email-to" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="email-subject" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="email-message" value="" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="file" name="file2" />
    <button type="submit" name="email-send">Skicka</button>
</form>
```

and the form-exec.php is, in my case, my PHPmailer sender!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is possible in IE9+ only.
To upload file 'ajax like' you should use iframe trick for that. 
I used that as source when implementing it:

http://ramui.com/articles/ajax-file-upload-using-iframe.html

Answer (score -3):

Apparently, FormData is not supported in IE. You may, however, be able to use jQuery's serialize like so:

```
        var FD = $('form').serialize();
```