# how to submit a form after a file has been uploaded while including some data in the post[]

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, phpexcel

hi i have following html form and i am using it to upload a .xlx file.

```
<form action="dashboard.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="file-upload">  


                                <div class="col-md-12 m-b-15">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        Note No :
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input class=" form-control m-b-15 " id="note_number_for_the_alert" name="note_number_for_the_alert" readonly="">                              
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 m-l-10">

                                        <div class=" formError validateAlert" id="alert_to_upload_file_in_vendor_delivery_note_management" >
                                            <div class="formErrorContent" id="test">please Select the .XLSX file <br></div>
                                            <div class="formErrorArrow"></div>                                
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="file" id="file" name="file2" multiple="multiple" />
                                        <p style="text-align: right; margin-top: 20px;">
                                            <input type="submit"  value="Upload Files" name="submit2" class= "btn btn-success" />
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </form>
```

following phpexcel code lines used to upload the file.

```
$uploadedStatus = 0;
$name2 = '';
if (isset($_POST["submit2"])) {
    if (isset($_FILES["file2"])) {

        if ($_FILES["file2"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        } else {
            if (file_exists($_FILES["file2"]["name"])) {
                unlink($_FILES["file2"]["name"]);
                $uploadedStatus = 2;
            }
            $name = basename($_FILES['file2']['name']);
            $name2 = explode('.', $name);
            if ($name2[count($name2) - 1] == 'csv' || $name2[count($name2) - 1] == 'xlsx') {

                $target_path = "uploads/programming/";
                $target_location = $target_path . basename($_FILES['file2']['name']);

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file2"]["tmp_name"], $target_location);
                $uploadedStatus = 1;
}


        }
    } else {
        echo "No file selected <br />";
    }
    }
}
```

these two working perfectly in separately , no issue with the file upload.
but i need to send some values to the dashboard.php using the same time.

currently before the file is uploading page is redirect to the dashboard.php, any suggestion to submit the form once  got $uploadedStatus = 1 where after the file uploading process has completed.

Comment: Are you using pure `PHP` or do you use `JavaScript` or `AJAX` to send and receive data ? and there's a typo at `class=" form control m-b-15 id="` is this a copy paste or your typed it ? also is this the complete code base for this question ?

Comment: use JS onclick event and push the message.

Comment: @Sand  i am using pure php for to submit data from one page to another after the file has uploaded. plz check the modification, i have only used the code for the question.

Comment: @RamuBhusal appreciate you could send me a example link, or code sample

Comment: I think the answer by Rinto will help or do you need more explaining ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you can use JQuery to upload the file. So the page won't get reload. When you press the upload button show an loading image tells the users that you are working on the upload.

```
<form action="dashboard.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_id">
```

**JQuery & Ajax**

```
function submitForm() {
  var formData = new FormData($("#form_id"));
  // show your loader image

    $.ajax({
        url: upload.php,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
           // hide your loader image
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
```

Note: Formdata won't work on older browsers. There are some fallback for that, read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852446/fallback-for-formdata-in-ie-8-9)

Comment: i am agreed to you Rinto, nice suggestion but little more thing to clarify how can i use  $target_path = "uploads/programming/"; while the jquery upload.i mean how to add/upload file to the particular folder.

Comment: What ajax does, it's just calling the PHP page upload.php. Ajax does not upload anything, it's your php script. So you can adjust your PHP file to change the dir whichever way you want. Keep this in mind, instead of Browser POST you are using Ajax, rest is PHP